# Markov Chain Arrows and Labels stacked together

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-pic

I am having challenges with the following:

1. My bottom chain arrows and labels (1-`\theta`) are stacked
   together/overlapping which is something I dont like, and
2. I want to add an extra broken line that goes to the left labeled
   `\theta` on top as shown in the picture below:
   [image: Desired Output]
   Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
Markov chain:   
\begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth', auto, semithick, node distance=3cm]
                \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,thick,text=black,scale=1]
                \node[state]    (A)                     {$0$};
                \node[state]    (B)[right of=A]   {$1$};
                \node[state]    (C)[right of=B]   {$2$};
                \node[state]    (D)[right of=C]   {$3$};
                \path
                (A) edge[loop left]         node{$1-\theta$}    (A)
                (B) edge[bend left,below]   node{$1-\theta$}    (A)
                edge[bend left,above]       node{$\theta$}  (C)
                (C) edge[bend left,below]   node{$1-\theta$}    (A)
                edge[bend left,above]       node{$\theta$}  (D)
                (D) edge[bend left,below]   node{$1-\theta$}    (A);
                %\node[above=0.5cm] (A){Patch G};
                %\draw[red] ($(D)+(-1.5,0)$) ellipse (2cm and 3.5cm)node[yshift=3cm]{Patch H};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest you accept one of the answers to your original question and post this as a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is like this:

[image]

```
%\documentclass{book}
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
                bbox,
                chains, 
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
%Markov chain:
%\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right, 
                        bezier bounding box,
     node distance = 22mm,
       start chain = going right, 
 every edge/.style = {draw, -Stealth, semithick},
every state/.style = {draw, thick, on chain}
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes=state]
\node (A)   {$0$};
\node (B)   {$1$};
\node (C)   {$2$};
\node (D)   {$3$};
\coordinate (E);
    \end{scope}
%
\path   (A) edge[loop left, looseness=12,  "$1-\theta$" '] (A);
\path[bend left, swap] 
        (A) edge["$\theta$"]    (B)
        (B) edge["$\theta$"]    (C)
        (C) edge["$\theta$"]    (D)
        (C) edge["$\theta$"]    (D)
        (D) edge[dashed, "$\theta$"]  (E);
\path[out=210]
        (B) edge[in=-30, "$1-\theta$"]  (A)
        (C) edge[in=-45, "$1-\theta$"]  (A)      
        (D) edge[in=-60, "$1-\theta$"]  (A);
            \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am getting many errors which include `Missing \endcsname inserted. ^^I\end{titlepage}` when I load the command `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
 bbox,
 chains, 
 positioning,
 quotes}` inside my document.

Comment: I tested MWE with recent MiKTeX. Result is showed in answer. It may help update your system. Libraries must be loaded in document preamble.

Comment: I updated my packages and I am left with one error: `Undefined control sequence. ... left, looseness=12, "$1-\theta$" '] (A)`

Comment: And also I think it's related to the ordering of the packages I loaded. Which packages should I start loading before loading the tikz related packages?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `tikz-cd`.

[image]

If you prefer the `1-\theta` labels above the arrows, you can change `"1-\theta", pos=.25` to `"1-\theta"'`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2cm, arrows={-Stealth}, cells={nodes={draw, circle, minimum size=8mm}}]
    0\arrow[r, bend left, "\theta"]\arrow[loop left, "1-\theta"]
    & 1\arrow[r, bend left, "\theta"]\arrow[l, bend left, "1-\theta", pos=.25]
    & 2\arrow[r, bend left, "\theta"]\arrow[ll, bend left, "1-\theta", pos=.25]
    & 3\arrow[r, dashed, bend left, "\theta"] \arrow[lll, bend left, "1-\theta", pos=.25]
    & |[draw=none]|
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I load the package `tikz-cd` I am getting a lot of errors including `Missing \endcsname inserted. ^^I\end{titlepage}`.

Comment: @itc: Try to compile only this code, with nothing else. If it doesn't work you have a problem with your installation. If it does work (more likely) then you have a bug somewhere else in the code where you're trying to add this. If you can't find it, try to make an example as short as possible with the error and perhaps ask a new question for help debugging.

Comment: The code is working perfectly when i compile it alone. However, when i add it into my document, that is when im getting these errors. What could be the cause? And are there packages that need to precede the tikz package in my preamble?

Comment: Is this diagram inside a figure? A bad label name can sometimes cause that error. But so can other things. Hard to guess without seeing your code. Try adding everything from `\begin{tikzcd}` to `\end{tikzcd}` to your document between `\[` and `\]` but not inside any other environment, and replace `\usepackage{tikz}` with `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` (since `tikz-cd` automatically loads `tikz`) and work from there.

Comment: The tikz-cd diagram is inside a figure environment, that is correct. Let me try your most recent comment. If that does not work, I will try to add some commands in my preamble to the MWE and then delete them later.

Comment: Kindly check the problem I am facing when I insert your code in my document.