# Tikz Code No Longer Running

Tags: tikz-cd, tikz-pic

This question follows from [Markov Chain Arrows and Labels stacked together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657358/markov-chain-arrows-and-labels-stacked-together?noredirect=1#comment1638106_657358) where I got 2 different solutions to my problem, the one provided by @Zarko which I accepted as my answer and also the one provided by @Sandy G. However, both solutions run perfectly without any errors before being incorporated in my main document. However, after being incorporated in my main document, I am beginning to get errors like `Undefined control sequence. ... left, looseness=12, "$1-\theta$" '] (A)` and `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 145.` I dont understand where the problem is given that the code works well outside my document. ANy help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my main document code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\usepackage[
a4paper,
left=1in,
right=1in, 
top=1in, 
bottom=1in
]{geometry}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}



\usepackage[marginal]{footmisc}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-3pt}%
    \hrule width 2in height 1.4pt \vspace*{2.6pt}}
\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}

\usepackage{titletoc}%this is an option [dotinlabels]
\usepackage[noindentafter,calcwidth]{titlesec}



\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ shapes.geometric }
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
    bbox,
    chains, 
    positioning,
    quotes}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[ragged]{sidecap}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[font=small,format=hang,skip=5pt,textfont=it]{caption}



%% This code creates the groups
% -----------------------------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{listings}


\usepackage[numbered, framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\let\ph\mlplaceholder % shorter macro
\lstMakeShortInline"
\makeatother

\makeatletter
% --------------------------------------- Matlab Output
\newcommand{\lstlistmatlaboutputname}{List of }
\newcounter{matlaboutput}
\lstnewenvironment{matlaboutput}[1][]{%
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Output}%
    \renewcommand{\ext@lstlisting}{loo}%
    %\xpatchcmd*{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lor}{}{}% use this with earlier version caption package
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{matlaboutput}}
    \lstset{
        language =Matlab,       
        style              = Matlab-editor,
        basicstyle         = \ttfamily\footnotesize,
,#1}}
{}

% --------------------------------------- Matlab Code
\newcommand{\lstlistmatlabcodename}{List of Codes}
\newcounter{matlabcode}
\lstnewenvironment{matlabcode}[1][]{%
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}%
    \renewcommand{\ext@lstlisting}{loc}%
    %\xpatchcmd*{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lop}{}{}% use this with earlier version caption package
    \setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{matlabcode}}
    \lstset{
        language =Matlab,       
        style              = Matlab-editor,
        basicstyle         = \ttfamily\footnotesize,
    ,#1}}
{}

% --------------------------------------- Pseudocode
\newcommand{\lstlistpseudocodename}{List of Pseudocode}
\lstnewenvironment{pseudocode}[1][]{%
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Pseudocode}%
    \renewcommand{\ext@lstlisting}{lop}%
    %\xpatchcmd*{\caption@ORI@lst@MakeCaption}{lol}{lor}{}{}% use this with earlier version caption package
    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1}}
{}

\newcommand{\lstlistofmatlaboutput}{\begingroup
    \tocfile{\lstlistmatlaboutputname}{loo}
    \endgroup}
\newcommand{\lstlistofmatlabcode}{\begingroup
    \tocfile{\lstlistmatlabcodename}{loc}
    \endgroup}
\newcommand{\lstlistofpseudocode}{\begingroup
    \tocfile{\lstlistpseudocodename}{lop}
    \endgroup}

\makeatother




\begin{document} 
    \sloppy
    
    \chapter{Sample Tikz}
    
    
    %Markov chain:
    %\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right, 
        bezier bounding box,
        node distance = 22mm,
        start chain = going right, 
        every edge/.style = {draw, -Stealth, semithick},
        every state/.style = {draw, thick, on chain}
        ]
        \begin{scope}[nodes=state]
            \node (A)   {$0$};
            \node (B)   {$1$};
            \node (C)   {$2$};
            \node (D)   {$3$};
            \coordinate (E);
        \end{scope}
        %
        \path   (A) edge[loop left, looseness=12,  "$1-\theta$" '] (A);
        \path[bend left, swap] 
        (A) edge["$\theta$"]    (B)
        (B) edge["$\theta$"]    (C)
        (C) edge["$\theta$"]    (D)
        (C) edge["$\theta$"]    (D)
        (D) edge[dashed, "$\theta$"]  (E);
        \path[out=210]
        (B) edge[in=-30, "$1-\theta$"]  (A)
        (C) edge[in=-45, "$1-\theta$"]  (A)      
        (D) edge[in=-60, "$1-\theta$"]  (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %\end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Trouble maker in your document is code line `\lstMakeShortInline"`, which change meaning of `"`. Consequently `quotes` syntax in `tikzpicture` doesn't work anymore. Try to limit this change to cases, where it is needed, for example by use etoolbox (sorry, I'm not familiar with listings package and I don't know, where you need this command) .

Comment: I need that command to produce <> in my listing environment. Is there a way of fixing that code?

Comment: For sure there is the way. Sorry, as I said, I'm not familiar with listings` so I can't help you in this. Check use of `listings` in the site or in its documentation or wait that some guru help you.

Comment: Try to change code line `\lstMakeShortInline"` to `\AtBeginEnvironment{listings}{\lstMakeShortInline"}` and see, if works for you.

Comment: Thank u very much @Zarko. Your comment solved my problem perfectly. I suggest u write it as a solution so that u earn your deserved reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your document preamble you have declaration `\lstMakeShortInline"` (defined in the `listings` package), which change standard meaning of `"` and by this clash with syntax of the Ti*k*Z library `quotes`.
- As cure you can limit this instruction to be used only in `listings` environments by use of the macro `\AtBeginEnvironment` defined in the `etoolbox`  package:

```
...
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\AtBeginEnvironment{listings}{\lstMakeShortInline"}
...
```

- Beside this it would be fine to clean your code of duplicate loading of `caption` package and delete lonely `\makeatother` instruction.