# How to place a tikz node at a lower level

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-pic

Using the solution provided by @Zarko at [Markov Chain Arrows and Labels stacked together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657358/markov-chain-arrows-and-labels-stacked-together?noredirect=1#comment1638106_657358), I want to know a way insert a node that is on  a lower level than the others as shown in the picture below:
[image]
I have successfully managed to create the 3 top nodes together with the arrows. The challenge is on creating a lower node together with the arrows. Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
    bbox,
    chains, 
    positioning,
    quotes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right, 
        bezier bounding box,
        node distance = 22mm,
        start chain = going right, 
        every edge/.style = {draw, -Stealth, semithick},
        every state/.style = {draw, thick, on chain}
        ]
        \begin{scope}[nodes=state]
            \node (A)   {$1$};
            \node (B)   {$2$};
            \node (C)   {$3$};
            \coordinate (E);
        \end{scope}
        %

        \path[bend left, swap] 
        (A) edge["$.25$"]    (B)
        (B) edge["$.125$"]    (C);

        \path[out=210]
        (B) edge[in=-30, "$.25$"]  (A);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can use `below=<distance> of <node>` syntax to place `4` node below `1` and shift it right via `xshift=`

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
    bbox,
    chains, 
    positioning,
    quotes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right, 
        bezier bounding box,
        node distance = 22mm,
        start chain = going right, 
        every edge/.style = {draw, -Stealth, semithick},
        every state/.style = {draw, thick, on chain}
        ]
        \begin{scope}[nodes=state]
            \node (A)   {$1$};
            \node (B)   {$2$};
            \node (C)   {$3$};
            \node[below=40pt of A, xshift=45pt] (D)   {$4$};
        \end{scope}
        %

        \path[bend left, swap] 
        (A) edge["$.25$"]    (B)
        (B) edge["$.125$"]    (C);
        
        \path 
        (A) edge["$.125$", bend right]      (D)
        (B) edge["$.125$", bend left, swap] (D);

        \path[out=210]
        (B) edge[in=-30, "$.25$"]  (A);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]